# How to convert CSV TEXT DATE To DATE in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, csv, odbc, openedge, progress-db

I am having to pull data from a CSV ODBC for a report i am running. One of the issues i am coming across is that the Invoice Date has become stored as text. The file i am pulling from has over 15 months of data but i am only look to capture data from the past 3 months.

When i use the standard `WHERE` clause saying `WHERE invoice date is greater than 2019-07-01`, this doesn't effect the data other than remove records with no invoice date.

I am looking for a way in my `WHERE` clause i can convert this text into the `DATE` format required to allow me to pull the relevant information. I have tried the below code but it appears the Progress ODBC does not like this as i get an error of: `Undefined Function 'CONVERT' in expression.`

Please see code below:

```
SELECT 
   AEOrdersReceived.`Order Company`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Description`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Ordered Outwork Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Sop Order Status`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Order Method`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Ordered VA Value`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Ordered Consumable Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Ordered Estimated Outwork Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Ordered Material Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Order Date`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Ordered Estimated Material Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Payment Method`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Job Number`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Required Date`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item First Delivery Date`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Sop Order Number`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Despatched Consumable Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Despatched Outwork Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Ordered Estimated Material Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Despatched Material Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Despatched VA Value`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Value`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Ordered Estimated Consumable Cost`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Ordered Estimated VA Value`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Invoice Number`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Invoice Date`,
   AEOrdersReceived.`Product Item Invoiced Sales Value`
FROM AEOrdersReceived.csv AEOrdersReceived
WHERE AEOrdersReceived.`Sop Order Number` >= 1168593
   AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, AEOrdersReceived.`Invoice Date`,102) > 2019-07-01
```

[image: Image illustrating current format]

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR, AEOrdersReceived.`Invoice Date`,102)` This is backwards.  You're converting it to varchar.  You need to convert to date to compare it with a date.  If a simple `convert(date,AEOrdersReceived.`Invoice Date`)` doesn't work then we'll need to see the input format.

Comment: Also put dates (and strings) in single quotes: `'2019-07-01'`

Comment: @avery_larry I made the change and the same error of: Undefined Function 'CONVERT' in expression came up when trying to execute

Comment: My apologies, I skipped right over that error message.  I'm not sure what's supported.  Try `cast(AEOrdersReceived.[Invoice Date] as date)`

Comment: We'd still like to see the format of [`Invoice Date]`.

Comment: @avery_larry It is formatted to the left when returned in excel under a general format it returns as DD/MM/YY. I will upload an image to illustrate

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and those dreaded backticks are invalid standard SQL). Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using...

Comment: Hello I had previously had tags on there - Its a progress openedge ODBC